# Javascript increment inside function not work

Tags: javascript

incrementation of c seems not to work inside a an if statement. However it works if placed just inside function. Also document.write does not work inside if statement. Any ideas?

```html
<html>
    <head>
        
    </head>

    <body>

        <p id="demo"></p>

        <script>
            var c = 0;

            function round (playerSelection = 'Rock' , computerSelection = 'Rock') {

                 if (playerSelection == 'Rock' && computerSelection == 'Rock') {
                     return 'draw';
                     c++; 
                     document.write (c); 
                     document.write("c"); 
                  }
    
            }
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = round();
            document.write (c); document.write("c"); 

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = round();` this makes no sense. You are saying set `innerHTML` of said element to the return value of `round()`, but `round()` returns nothing (most of the time). Just writes directly to the document. Also `return` stops executing rest of the code in the function (anything after it is ignored).

Comment: the return is the first thing in if check. so you exit it right away.put it at the last after `document.write("c");`

Comment: TIP: Also try to add `else{}` section with buggy `if` to see if the `if` statement is actually failing or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you return, you exit the function

```
if (playerSelection == 'Rock' && computerSelection == 'Rock') {
       
                 return 'draw';
                 c++; 
                 document.write (c); 
                 document.write("c"); 
              }
```

Therefor the c++; line is never reached.
Move the return to the bottom of the if statement

Answer (score 1):

Here is the working code -

```html
<html>
    <head>
        
    </head>

    <body>

        <p id="demo"></p>

        <script>
            var c = 0;

            function round (playerSelection = 'Rock' , computerSelection = 'Rock') {

                 if (playerSelection == 'Rock' && computerSelection == 'Rock') {
                     c++; 
                     document.write (c); 
                     document.write("c");
                     return 'draw';
                  }
    
            }
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = round();
            document.write (c); document.write("c"); 

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```